# how to check if the user is already available in mysql or not

Tags: mysql, sails.js

Here I am storing username and password. The data are stored in mysql but I have to check the username is already available or not

Also, how to get response in the UI side to display whether the user is creater or not.(like in alert box)

```
    signup: function(req,res){

    if(req.method=="POST")
        {
            console.log("Post");
            var username = req.param("username");
            var password =req.param("password");
            console.log(username);

            var insert = "INSERT INTO signup(username,password) VALUES("+username+",'"+password+"')";

            signup.query(insert,function(err,record)
            {

                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(record);
                    res.redirect('User/index');
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            res.render("create");
        }
},
```

Comment: Just add a unique index on the username field, perform the insert, and if you get a duplicate username error, then you know that the username exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findOrCreate](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create).

```
Signup.findOrCreate({
  username: username
}, {
  username: username,
  password: password
}).exec(<callback>);
```